# Attempting to append all content into file, last iteration is the only one filling text document

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to Create a file and append all the content being calculated into that file, but when I run the script the very last iteration is written inside the file and nothing else.

My code is on pastebin, it's too long, and I feel like you would have to see exactly how the iteration is happening.

Try to summarize it, Go through an array of model numbers, if the model number matches call the function that calculates that MAC_ADDRESS, when done calculating store all the content inside a the file.

I have tried two possible routes and both have failed, giving the same result. There is no error in the code (it runs) but it just doesn't store the content into the file properly there should be 97 different APs and it's storing only 1.

The difference between the first and second attempt,

1 attempt) I open/create file in the beginning of the script and close at the very end.

2 attempt) I open/create file and close per-iteration.

First Attempt:

https://pastebin.com/jCpLGMCK

```
#Beginning of code
File = open("All_Possibilities.txt", "a+")

#End of code
File.close()
```

Second Attempt:

https://pastebin.com/cVrXQaAT

```
#Per function
File = open("All_Possibilities.txt", "a+")

#per function
File.close()
```

If I'm not suppose to reference other websites, please let me know and I'll just paste the code in his post.

Comment: Please narrow this down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Likely this will even lead you to figuring out the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `close()`, please use [`with`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python):

```
with open('All_Possibilities.txt', 'a') as file_out:
    file_out.write('some text\n')
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) explains that you don't need `+` to append writes to a file.

You may want to add some debugging console `print()` statements, or use a debugger like [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), to verify that the `write()` statement actually ran, and that the variable you were writing actually contained the text you thought it did.

You have several loops that could be a one-liner using [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines).

Please do this:

```
$ pip install flake8
$ flake8 *.py
```

That is, please run the flake8 lint utility against your source code,
and follow the advice that it offers you.
In particular, it would be *much* better to name your identifier `file` than to name it `File`.
The initial capital letter means something to humans reading your code -- it is
used when naming classes, rather than local variables. Good luck!